# Set breakpoints in multiple dlls

Tags: c#, .net, breakpoints

How can i set break points across multiple dlls, and be able to use them in one debugging session?

I have an application `a.exe`, and two dlls `b.dll` and `c.dll`, all three of which are my code. `a.exe` makes use of classes contained in b and c.

What i want to able to do, is set a breakpoint in b.dll, and have visual studio break at that point in the ide. At present, i can step into the relevant methods in the dlls, but breakpoints dont seem to work. What do i need to do to get this working?

Comment: If you can step into them you should be able to set breakpoints.  Double check you have the PDB files for the dlls in the same folder as the dlls and the exe

Comment: Are the code projects for all of your DLLS included in the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty trivial if I understand you right. Each of those dll's has a source out of which they are compiled. Just find the sources for those dll's by checking your project list within the solution and looking at "properties".

Something you should double check is to have them compiled for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't set Breakpoints in visual studio the "usual" way, you can always add this line when you want to break:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

It does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

using System.Diagnostics;

Debug.WriteLine("Debug Information Here");

There are more debug option !

You can also step into the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the projects as part of one solution and you are running your exe as start up project under DEBUG mode you should be able to hit the breakpoints. Just make sure that the project is build under DEBUG mode.